# How can I split a delimited list and recombine the values into a hash map?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

I've been writing the following to try to better understand hash maps. I have an original list of items separated by the delimiter `|`. The goal is to ensure the at the end I have a HashMap where there is one key for each letter, i.e. `a` that appears before the `|` and attached to each letter a list containing the associated "logs", or that which appears after the `|`, i.e. a = [asdf a2, asdf a1]. I put the a1/a2 in the "log" portion of the list just for clarity. Assume that when really executing this code those hints won't be there. I just want to group all the "logs" to their appropriate key based on the initial raw delimited list.

**Program:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

        // Set up raw data
        items.add("a|asdf a2");
        items.add("b|asdf b1");
        items.add("c|asdf c1");
        items.add("c|asdf c2");
        items.add("c|asdf c3");
        items.add("d|asdf d1");
        items.add("a|asdf a1");
        items.add("e|asdf e1");
        items.add("e|asdf e2");
        items.add("e|asdf e3");
        items.add("e|asdf e4");

        // Display raw data
        System.out.println("Raw List: " + items);

        // Create a hash map
        HashMap<String, List<String>> customerHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Create new lists. One for customers and one for logs
        List<String> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> logList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String item : items) {
            String customer = item.split("\\|", 2)[0];
            customerList.add(customer);

            String log = item.substring(item.indexOf("|") + 1);
            logList.add(log);

            // Add to hash map
            customerHashMap.put(customer, logList);
        }

        // Display lists
        System.out.println("Customer List: " + customerList);
        System.out.println("Log List: " + logList);
        System.out.println("Hashmap: " + customerHashMap);

        // Print out of the final hash map. Customer a should only have "a" logs, customer b with "b", etc.
        System.out.println("");
        Iterator it = customerHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            it.remove();
        }

    }
```

**Output:**

```
a = [asdf a2, asdf b1, asdf c1, asdf c2, asdf c3, asdf d1, asdf a1, asdf e1, asdf e2, asdf e3, asdf e4]
b = [asdf a2, asdf b1, asdf c1, asdf c2, asdf c3, asdf d1, asdf a1, asdf e1, asdf e2, asdf e3, asdf e4]
c = [asdf a2, asdf b1, asdf c1, asdf c2, asdf c3, asdf d1, asdf a1, asdf e1, asdf e2, asdf e3, asdf e4]
d = [asdf a2, asdf b1, asdf c1, asdf c2, asdf c3, asdf d1, asdf a1, asdf e1, asdf e2, asdf e3, asdf e4]
e = [asdf a2, asdf b1, asdf c1, asdf c2, asdf c3, asdf d1, asdf a1, asdf e1, asdf e2, asdf e3, asdf e4]\
```

**Desired Output:**

```
a = [asdf a2, asdf a1]
b = [asdf b1]
c = [asdf c1, asdf c2, asdf c3]
d = [asdf d1]
e = [asdf e1, asdf e2, asdf e3, asdf e4]
```

How can I achieve this desired output at the end?

Comment: You want one separate log list for each customer, and yet you're creating a single log list. How could that work?

Comment: Consider using a [Guava ListMultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html).

Comment: @JBNizet That makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> logList = new ArrayList<>();
```

is declared before the loop and this variable is never reassigned.
And you use it as value associated to every key of the `Map` in the loop .
So all keys of the map refer to the same `ArrayList` object.

You have to create a new `ArrayList` and associate it to a key in the map (`put(key,value)`) for each distinct key.

This could give :

```
    for (String item : items) {
        String customer = item.split("\\|", 2)[0];
        customerList.add(customer);

        String log = item.substring(item.indexOf("|") + 1);
        List<String> logList = customerHashMap.get(customer);
        if (logList == null){
          logList = new ArrayList<>();
          customerHashMap.put(customer, logList);
        }           
        logList.add(log);
    }
```

Or as  JB Nizet suggests, use `Map.computeIfAbsent()` (since Java 8) that spares you both to explicitly write the not exist check and to declare an intermediary local variable to refer to the current `ArrayList` object.

```
    for (String item : items) {
        String customer = item.split("\\|", 2)[0];
        customerList.add(customer);

        String log = item.substring(item.indexOf("|") + 1);
        customerHashMap.computeIfAbsent(customer, c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(log);
    }
```

Comment: Or you could use the shortcut method designed for that frequent use-case: `customerHashMap.computeIfAbsent(customer, c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(log);`

Comment: Optimization idea: no need to recompute `log`; it's already in `item.split("\\|", 2)[1]`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You are right. But to be exact, it is already in `item.split("\\|", 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java 8 new features for your requirement.
With this simple line of code, you can achieve your requirement:

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), Collectors.mapping(s -> s.substring(2), Collectors.toSet()))).forEach((k,v)-> {
        System.out.println(k + " = " + v);
    });
```

The end of forEach function is to print the result, but the code result is a Map with your desired results:

```
Map<Character, Set<String>> result = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), Collectors.mapping(s -> s.substring(2), Collectors.toSet())));
```

**Note**: use **Collectors.toList()** if the elements can be repeated

Comment: you are not splitting the last to elements

Comment: @Schidu Luca the original item List is splitted, no need to split :)